# Prevent Cart Drawer Popup When Clicking Quick Add Button on Shopify Prestige

Tags: popup, shopify, liquid, cart

I am using the Prestige theme on my Shopify store, and I have implemented a quick add button for each product item image. However, I would like to restrict the appearance of any popup cart drawer when users click on the quick add button. Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

I have already tried researching this issue in the theme documentation and searching for solutions online, but I haven't found any relevant information specific to the Prestige theme. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to customize the theme or provide a code snippet that can help me prevent the cart drawer from appearing when the quick add button is clicked.

Thank you in advance for your help.

I was advised to set the cart type to Message in the theme settings, and that was to solve my issue, but perhaps i have only in my theme "page" or "drawer" cart type.

I tried following any event lister of that popup in theme.js, but i couldnt find it..

Please refer to my website for your reference https://winnerforce-lb.com/

Answer (score 0):

The function that triggers the sidebar cart on quick add to cart is called `onQuickBuyButtonClicked` and it can be found under custom.js.

```
// add product with size swatches js
function onQuickBuyButtonClicked(id, pro_id) {
    const CartCount = document.getElementsByClassName('Header__CartCount')[0];

    $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--adding");
    const product = {
        id: id,
        quantity: 1
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/cart/add.js',
        data: JSON.stringify(product),
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        success: function(cart) {
            setTimeout(function() {
               $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");
                $(".loader_" + id).addClass("add-success--added");
              cartRecommended(pro_id); // remove this to stop the recommendations from displaying every time the user adds to cart.
            }, 500);

            setTimeout(function() {
                document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('product:added', {
                    bubbles: true,
                    detail: {
                        variant: cart,
                        quantity: 1
                    }
                })); // play around with this line to see if it triggers the sidebar-cart to display
            }, 1200);

            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding").removeClass("add-success--added");
              
            }, 1600);
          setTimeout(function() {
          $('#backdrop').addClass('backdrop_active'); // remove this since it triggers the dark overlay background
          }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown) {
            $(".loader_" + id).removeClass("add-success--adding");

            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(errorThrown.responseText);
            $(".error_" + pro_id).html("Error: " + r.description).show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(".error_" + pro_id).html("").hide(100);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });
return false;
}
```